# Nginx cache static files (vagrant+nginx+uwsgi+flask)

Tags: caching, nginx, vagrant, static-files

When I reload static files I don't see changes but � characters.

I have turned off "sendfile" parameter in nginx configuration but it doesn't fix it.

I'm using: https://github.com/linssen/vagrant-puppet-nginx-uwsgi-flask